# SSL Redirect Loop - Was working fine with no changes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have a free SSL certificate from StartSSL. It expires in May of 2016. Last week, the site was loading fine. However, whenever I try to go to it, I get a redirect loop error. The .htaccess has these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which force the HTTPS, and it has worked fine up until now. I installed the certificate using cpanel 6 months ago and there were no issues and I have not made a change to the site in over 6 months.

I click the connection in Google Chrome when it gives me the redirect loop error and it says "Your connection to this site is not private" -- I'm not sure if that's because it's not loaded?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Several of the browsers have made the choice to start marking / blocking SSL certificates that don't meet certain standards (SHA 2, TLS 1.0).  I say block because some users see the scary message and wouldn't proceed, because they don't know better.  The SSL being free, might mean that it falls in this category.  If you are using a hosting company, they probably did something.  Can you clarify any of this?  The hash of the cert, your server or hosted.  Does it work in any other browser?

Comment: When viewing the certificate, the version is V3. The signature algorithm sha256RSA. The signature hash algorithm is sha256. The thumbprint algorithm is sha1. The public key is RSA (2048 Bits). Where can I see the standards for the browsers so I can check more in detail if this information all seems correct?

Comment: My certificate has the sha256, but when I view the other two above mine, they say sha1. I'm sure you're correct and that's the cause. Is there a way to get a free certificate with the secure standards needed now?

Comment: How are you even running a site? I ask this because why do you expect a free cert for your personal or business site? Not trying to sound rude but common they're not that expensive. [$5 a year!](https://www.ssls.com/ssl-certificates/comodo-positivessl)

Comment: Here is a post about Chrome specifically:  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86145/why-is-my-positive-ssl-certificate-deemed-insecure-by-google-chrome  If you got the SSL from a hosting company, bug them.  Maybe they will cough up a new cert for you.  Otherwise, you will probably have to eat the cost.

Comment: Panama Jack - Thanks for the link. All I could find was the $60-$90 certs, and I don't want to spend $6000+ on certificates if I don't have to. It's weird, though. Only one site had the problem, and when I commented out the two rules, https loaded fine.